# Remove method in HashMap java does not work

Tags: java, hashmap

I have removed the map with the method `"remove(key)"` but just the value was deleted. When I call the `keySet()` method. The key still there!!.
The below program, I want to find two groups (2 map in the HashMap) have shortest distance. Then merge them, that mean I need to remove these two groups and put the merged group to maps.

```
/* I have already initiate the HashMap groups*/
ArrayList<String> listGroupNames ;
while (currentNumberOfGroup > 1000){
  System.out.println("Groups" + currentNumberOfGroup);
  listGroupNames  =  new ArrayList<String>(groups.keySet());
  /*  Name of two groups will be merged*/
  String candidate1 = "";
  String candidate2 = "";
  double maxSimilarity = 0;

  /* finding two groups which have shortest distance*/
  for(String event1 : listGroupNames){
    for(String event2 : listGroupNames){
      if(!event1.equalsIgnoreCase(event2)){
          Group group1 = groups.get(event1);
          Group otherGrp = groups.get(event2);
          double similarity = group1.getMaxSimilarityWith(otherGrp, simpledEvent);
          if(similarity > maxSimilarity){
            maxSimilarity = similarity;
            candidate1 = event1;
            candidate2 = event2;
          }
      }
    }
  }
  /*  2 groups have shortest distance were found already*/
  /* Merge 2 groups then replace these two groups by merged group*/
  Group groupCandidate1 = groups.get(candidate1) ;
  Group groupCandidate2 = groups.get(candidate2) ;
  Group mergerdGroup = groupCandidate1.mergeToOtherGroup(groupCandidate2);
  /*remove 2 found groups*/
  groups.remove(candidate2);
  groups.remove(candidate1);

  groups.put(mergerdGroup.name, mergerdGroup);
  listGroupNames.clear();
  currentNumberOfGroup --;      
}
```

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - The keys appear to be String ...

Comment: The thing that puzzles me is how you "know" that the key is still there.  I think we need an SSCCE to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: Regardless, it'll help to see `groupCandidate1.mergeToOtherGroup` so we know how `mergerdGroup.name` is determined.

Comment: @StephenC: in next iteration, I have an error, I tried to print the groups had made error, it appears that these group had been already  merged and removed.

Comment: @PaulBellora: It's quite simple.

Comment: @HoaVu - we need an SSCCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included enough code to allow us to properly diagnose the problem, so this is a general answer.

You assert that you have removed a key using `groups.remove(key)`, but the key is still present when you look at the keys via the object returned via `groups.keyset()`.

This is a "cannot happen".  If a key is removed, it won't be in the keyset.  Furthermore, since the keys are (it appears) `String` objects, we can virtually exclude the possibility that there is a problem with `equals` and `hashcode`.

So what possible explanations are there?  Here are some.

- The `groups` objects in the two contexts are different.
- Something is adding back the key or keys between the removal and the examination of the keyset.  (For example, `mergerdGroup.name` is actually equal to either `candidate1` or `candidate2`.)
- The keys are not actually the same ... they just look the same.

Comment: Thank you. I find it is very hard to me upload all the code. It's very complex. I will review the code as you suggested.

Comment: @HoaVu - an SSCCE doesn't mean "upload all of the code".  It means create a *small* working example that exhibits the same problem.